# Is there a way to download the question like a pdf/latex?

Tags: feature-request, export

I saw some very nice proofs online, and it seems that the only way I can get it in collection was to favorite the question.

However, is there a way to download the question/posts or specific answer like a pdf/latex file?

Comment: You can go to "edit" and then copy the source code and paste it into a latex file and compile it.

Comment: @AlexanderGruber Yeah, I did that before. However, I was worried that I might click the wrong button, and the "edit" doesn't copy any reference or citation.  It's kind of strange that they have the cite button, not download button.

Comment: Related: [How to archive and backup our questions to our own PC just in case?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25162/how-to-archive-and-backup-our-questions-to-our-own-pc-just-in-case)

Comment: There are several older posts about this (in fact you can see some of them in the list of related question in the sidebar). For example: [Save the answer in PDF?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15163), [Save the answer in TEX?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15230) and [Save the answer in TeX/PDF - revisioned](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/25175).

Comment: There are also some related posts on Meta Stack Exchange - see [Printing out Stack Overflow/Exchange Q&As including comments?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22877) and the [questions linked there](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/22877).

Comment: @AlexanderGruber The fundamental structure of the input code is not LaTeX, it's Markdown and there are plenty of tools for processing Markdown. One easy to use command line tool is [PanDoc](https://pandoc.org/), which I used to generate [this PDF](https://www.marksmath.org/temp/temp.pdf) from [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/292275/discontinuous-derivative/423279#423279). All the math is formatted correctly, as are the images, links, and structure. One could convert to LaTeX, if one wanted.